# salesforce plugin for visual studio code

Tags: force.com, editor

Has anyone used Visual Studio for Salesforce? Currently, I'm using Eclipse for that but it is very heavy and slows down my PC.

The alternative seems to be **mavensmate** but now it seems, it is not available.

Also, Salesforce has recently released beta version of Visual Studio Code Extension and there are already lot of other extensions available like [mavensmate](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DavidHelmer.mavensmate), [Apex Code Editor for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode-apex), [ForceCode](https://johnaaronnelson.gitbooks.io/forcecode/content/#overview), [Visual Studio Code Extension Pack for Salesforce DX](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode).
Is it really good alternative of Eclipse?

Comment: It's also worth looking at Illuminated Cloud (a plugin for IntelliJ IDEA). http://www.illuminatedcloud.com/ My team just moved from MavensMate to IC. It is being actively developed (e.g. SF DX support was recently added) and works really well for us. It costs $65 as a one-off, but that's peanuts really, if you like it. Having spoken to people inside SF, their intention is to support an ecosystem of tools such as IC, as well as doing whatever they are doing with VS Code.

Answer (score 2):

I working on Visual Studio code for 5 month. For me is fine - I develope more lightning components than apex but I recomended below (only to salesforce) currently using by me:

1. [Lightning Component Code Editor for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode-lightning) and [Lightning Component Code Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode-lightning)
2. [ForceCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JohnAaronNelson.ForceCode) and [vsforce](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=coveo.vsforce)
3. [Apex Code Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode-apex) and [Apex](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JohnAaronNelson.apex)
4. [salesforce Language supprot](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=chuckjonas.apex-autocomplete)